# Need to change color of text on input form on mobile site

Tags: css, joomla, mobile-website

I have recently made my website responsive, it is a joomla site, and on the mobile version anywhere that I have a form, when you type in the text you can barely see it because of the color. I have been playing around in the css trying to add color to it but to no avail. Could you please help me crack this thing, it is driving me nuts and several people that have tried using the form have complained about it. The website is www.destinychurchjacksonville.com and the online giving is an example of where it does this. Thank you a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 368 of black.css there is a css rule for `input[type="text"]` that sets the `color: #ccc;` a light grey. If you can edit the file black.css and change the color property value to #000 (black) as so: `color: #000;`

On the non-mobile site the input field inherits the color property from the body element and is thus black.

Let me know if you need more details on the above.

Comment: David, I got it. I was trying to edit the main.css and couldn't see the black.css. I hade to go into my ftp to find it, Joomla wasn't showing it under the css pages that it shows within it. I changed what you told me too and one other one as it was one color when inputting the text and then another after. So you helped me find it. Thank you. It won't let me give you a vote up b/c my reputation isn't high enough. Which sucks b/c you deserve one! Thank you.

Comment: So what you can do is mark my answer as correct - which will provide the equivalent of an upvote :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers you can read about it here. I'll upvote your question when I get more votes in two hours and then you'll be a step closer to being able to upvote!